# Delete an element of certain value in numpy array once

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to delete an element from a numpy array that has a certain value. However, in the case there are multiple elements of the same value, I only want to delete one occurrence (doesn't matter which one). That is:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9])
```

How do I delete one instance of 8? Specifically

```
a_new = np.delete(a, np.where(a == 8))
print(a_new)
```

removes all 8's.

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem. Why are you trying to delete anything from a numpy array to begin with?

Comment: It's a pattern matching step. Then I continue with the use of numpy arrays.

Comment: You reallocate the entire array to delete one element. Sounds like masking might be a better way potentially.

Comment: That's true. How can masking be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply choose one of the indices:

```
In [3]: np.delete(a, np.where(a == 8)[0][0])
Out[3]: array([1, 1, 2, 6, 8, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is at least one `8` you can use `argmax`:

```
np.delete(a,(a==8).argmax())
# array([1, 1, 2, 6, 8, 8, 9])
```

If not you can still use this method but you have to do one check:

```
idx = (a==8).argmax()
if a[idx] == 8:
    result = np.delete(a,idx)
else: # no 8 in a
    # complain
```