# Delete array of values from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This post is an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430362/delete-an-element-of-certain-value-in-numpy-array-once).

I would like to delete multiple elements from a numpy array that have certain values. That is for

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9])
```

How do I delete one instance of each value of [1,5,8], such that the output is `[1,2,6,8,8,9]`. All I have found in the documentation for an array removal is the use of `np.setdiff1d`, but this removes all instances of each number. How can this be updated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete rows from numpy array depending on a condition on a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016684/delete-rows-from-numpy-array-depending-on-a-condition-on-a-single-cell)

Comment: In the example above, I want to remove the values 1,5, and 8. These integers refer to the values I want to remove, not the index of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using outer comparison and `argmax` to only remove once.  For large arrays this will be memory intensive, since the created mask has `a.shape * r.shape` elements.

---

```
r = np.array([1, 5, 8])
m = (a == r[:, None]).argmax(1)
np.delete(a, m)
```

```
array([1, 2, 6, 8, 8, 9])
```

---

This *does* assume that each value in `r` appears in `a` at least once, otherwise the value at index `0` will get deleted since `argmax` will not find a match, and will return `0`.

Comment: I don't understand the notation used to define `m`. Could you explain that?

Comment: It's just broadcasted comparison to compare row-wise each value in `r` with all of array `a`.

Comment: Is it more efficient to use this approach as opposed to LampToasts approach?

Comment: Time it on your data, but it should be much faster.

Comment: There's no performance difference. They're functionally identical

Comment: @LampToast not quite right.  Using vectorized operations will beat loops in most cases.  If you want, time it and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

```py
delNums = [np.where(a == x)[0][0] for x in [1,5,8]]
a = np.delete(a, delNums)
```

here, `delNums` contains the indexes of the values 1,5,8 and np.delete() will delete the values at those specified indexes

OUTPUT:

```
[1 2 6 8 8 9]
```